# Merge 2 MP3 files Android

Tags: android, eclipse

I would like to know is there a way to merge 2 MP3 files into one. Basically I have a song and a rain sounds as a mp3 files, I would liek to merge them and as a result to get same song with rain sounds in backgroud. Is there any way to do this? Or some sort of ecternal SDK that can be used in this situation?

Comment: I'm a little confused as to what exactly you're asking. Are you looking for how to do this in Java for an Android app?

Comment: Sorry for confusion, pure android programming.

Comment: Have a look at:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13656559/join-mp3-files-converting-java-code-to-android][1]

and 
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6731155/how-to-merge-two-mp3-files-into-one-combine-join][2]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13656559/join-mp3-files-converting-java-code-to-android
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6731155/how-to-merge-two-mp3-files-into-one-combine-join

Comment: @user2163205 did u get the solution for your problem ?